# Is it possible to enable HMR on a shopify rails app using react webpacker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, webpack, shopify, hot-module-replacement

I want to speed up development time when creating shopify apps. A lot of my time is spent waiting for the page to reload through the ngrok portal so I can see my changes.

I want to enable HMR so the reload happens a lot faster.

I am currently using rails 6 and react via webpack, along with the shopify polaris react components.

I have struggled to get the ./bin/webpack-dev-server --hot running as it comes up on a different port and can trigger the Shopify CORS error. I've managed to get that going (I think) through ngrok tunnels.

I then tried to follow this https://gaearon.github.io/react-hot-loader/getstarted/ however I couldn't get it going and while changes look to be compiling on my server, the page is never updated. I've currently reverted my index.js file without hot loading changes. Any help getting my index.js file setup correctly is appreciated.

My index.js file looks like:

```
// Run this example by adding <%= javascript_pack_tag 'hello_react' %> to the head of your layout file,
// like app/views/layouts/application.html.erb. All it does is render <div>Hello React</div> at the bottom
// of the page.

import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import { AppContainer } from 'react-hot-loader';
import App from '../components/App'


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router>
      <Route path="/" component={App} />
    </Router>,
    document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
  )
})
```

Has anybody got HMR working with shopify through ngrok? Would be nice to know if it's even possible.

I would also be interested (and probably many others as well!) in any other shopify app time saving tips!

All help is highly appreciated!

Comment: were you ever able to figure this out? I am facing the same issue and its super annoying having to reload every time.

Comment: No I wasn't. It is really annoying! I gave up and now live with it. Wish there was a better way. Did you end up finding a solution?